# Clean statement for value passing with afterburner fx in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, parameter-passing

I use the afterburner.fx framework for the javafx program as follows,

NameModel  used for sharing the state between views or the implementation of business logic.

```
public class NameModel {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String value) {
        name.set(value);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

SchoolPresenter I used to enter the value for NameModel.If the name in Model get value starting with character
starts with "A",I pass that name to ClassAPresenter and it is similar to names starting with character B, C ...for ClassB,ClassC...

```
public class SchoolPresenter implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane;

    @Inject NameModel nameModel;
    private ClassAView classAView;
    private ClassBView classBView;
    private ClassCView classCView;
    .............................
    private ClassNView classNView;

    @FXML
    void txtName(ActionEvent event) {
        String name=txtName.getText();
        if (!name.isEmpty()) {

        //My program runs fine not wrong but
        //If I have N classes, and with declarations for the same classes below
        //the program will be very confusing
        //Please help me to collapse my code

            if(name.startWith("A")){
                if (classAView == null) {
                    classAView = new ClassAView();
                    ClassAPresenter classAPresenter = (ClassAPresenter) classAView.getPresenter();
                    classAPresenter.initNameModel(nameModel);

                    stackPane.getChildren().add(classAView.getView());
                }
            }else if(name.startWith("B")){
                    classBView = new ClassBView();

                    ClassBPresenter classAPresenter = (ClassBPresenter) classBView.getPresenter();
                    classBPresenter.initNameModel(nameModel);

                    stackPane.getChildren().add(classBView.getView());
            }else if.............//

            nameModel.setName(txtName.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

The ClassAPresenter, ClassBPresenter ...ClassNPresenter is structured as follows

```
public class ClassAPresenter  implements Initializable {

    private NameModel nameModel;

    public void initDomainModel(NameModel nameModel) {
        // ensure model is only set once:
        if (this.nameModel != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
        }
        this.nameModel = nameModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: "My program runs fine ... Please help me to collapse my code" then Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask this question. Please re-post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review

Comment: What is the difference between the different `ClassXView` and/or `ClassXPresenter`s? It seems like this could simply be a single view/presenter pair to which you pass a parameter. And why are you passing the `NameModel` to the other presenters manually, instead of just injecting it with `@Inject` (isn't that the whole point of afterburner.fx)?

Comment: I do not think it can be automated, I tested it on your hint that it was a success.Thank James_D

Comment: I know of afterburner from the articles that pass your parameters, but I do not yet understand the power of it, thanks for your suggestion yesterday my program became clean much work was shortened

I am so happy.I want to thank you again,thank you very much @James_D